# laravel, migration reference table string format on delete cascade

Tags: php, sql, laravel

How can I make  relation between two table using string format? I'm getting the error

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
>   `...`.`ordercustomizes` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is
>   incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `ordercustomizes` add
>   constraint `ordercustomizes_userorder_id_foreign` foreign key
>   (`userorder_id`) references `userorders` (`order_number`) on delete
>   cascade)

```
    Schema::create('ordercustomizes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('userorder_id');
        $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('customizetitle_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('customizeproduct_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('userorder_id')
            ->references('order_number')
            ->on('userorders')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
```

main table:

```
   Schema::create('userorders', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('storeinfo_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
         $table->string('order_number');
```

Comment: why string format ?

Comment: because Im storing the order number in string format and impossible to change it due to the system

Comment: then why not just reference the userorders_id of since its just the same ?

Comment: please ccan you help me to do this for string reference?

Comment: check first the order of your migration, the ordercustomizes and must be after userorders.

Comment: yes it is after userorders

Comment: I think you need to create an index on the string field (order_number).
Something like : `$table->index('order_number');`

Comment: you mean like this? $table->string('userorder_id')->unsigned()->index();

Comment: Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `...`.`ordercustomizes` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `ordercustomizes` add constraint `ordercustomizes_userorder_id_foreign` foreign key (`userorder_id`) references `userorders` (`order_number`) on delete cascade)

Comment: No, In the `userorders` table creation.
`$table->string('order_number')->index();`
If the table already exists, alter the table instead.
I'm not completely sure this will fix your problem, and I can't try it for you. So don't try it in production :)

Comment: If the `order_number` field already exists, you have to use `$table->index('order_number');` instead of `$table->string('order_number')->index();` (the last will try to create a new field, while the first one alter an existing field)

Comment: Cool :) I will put it in an answer so that it could be useful for other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an index for the `order_number` field (in `userorders` table)  first.

You can do it at table creation using: `$table->string('order_number')->index();`
Or you can alter the existing table and just create a new index using: `$table->index('order_number');`